# The inline keyboard buttons are not displayed in pyrogram

Tags: pyrogram

```
from pyrogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton


    inline_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
        inline_keyboard=[
            [
                InlineKeyboardButton('ОПУБЛИКОВАТЬ', url='https://t.me/adwert22_bot'),
                InlineKeyboardButton('ОПУБЛИКОВАТЬ', url='https://t.me/adwert22_bot')
            ]
        ]
    )


async def new_post(client: Client, message: Message):  # Функция будет запускаться при поступлении новых сообщений
    await client.send_message(chat_id=technical_channel, text="ОТПРАВЛЯЕМ?", reply_markup=inline_keyboard)
```

the text is displayed, but without buttons

Comment: Are you using Pyrogram with a User or Bot account? Users cannot attach an Inline Keyboard.